# What is the probability that at least $N$ players out of $M$ flip heads $R$ times in a row?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let's say $M$ people gather to play heads or tails. They each flip their coin $R$ times and count the heads. What is the probability that at least $N$ of them (of course $N < M$) hit heads $R$ times (perfect score) ?

I can do the combinatorics by brute force for small values of $M$ and $R$, and $N = 1$, but have trouble generalizing it to a formula tractable even for large numbers and any value of $N$. Any hint is appreciated.

**Background**: I realize this looks like straight out from a textbook assignment (^_^;)
The motivation is I had a discussion with people who take the existence of US [bellwether counties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_election_bellwether_counties_in_the_United_States#:%7E:text=Election%20bellwether%20counties%20in%20the%20United%20States%20are%20counties%20that,who%20ultimately%20wins%20the%20election.) and the fact that 18 out of 19 selected the loosing candidate in the recent presidential election as a proof of massive fraud, on grounds of the improbability they could be right for 40 years and then wrong. Instinctively, I don't find it improbable that 19 counties out of 3243 have a "winning streak" of 10 "successes", which would mean there is nothing special about those counties and their existence can be pure dumb luck, but can't make formally sure of it, which has bugged me for a few days now.

Comment: When discussing coin flipping, using the symbol $T$ to represent *times* rather than *tails* is likely to confuse readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\displaystyle \sum_{i=N}^M {M \choose i} (.5^T)^i (1-.5^T)^{M-i}$

Explanation: i people hit heads T times in a row. The probability of hitting heads T times in a row is .5^T, and this happens i times. The rest of them don't hit heads T times in a row, so it's 1 minus that probability. This happens for the remaining M-i people. And you need to choose which of the M people hit heads T times in a row. Sum this for each i from N to M.

Comment: Thanks for the formula. Unfortunately the very huge factorials and very small probabilities brought my computing program to its knees and even Wolfram Alpha. I will have to do some optimization, that's gonna be fun.

Comment: This is simple cumulative binomial distribution and should be easy to calculate. For large M, you should also be able to use normal approximation.  What is the typical size of your M?